# C++ friend function reference to global enum from inside namespace

Tags: c++, c++14

The following friend declaration for **FriendlyAccess** compiles under C++98 (gcc 4.4.7):

```
typedef enum MyError
{
    SUCCESS = 0,
    FAILURE = 1
} MyError;

MyError FriendlyAccess();

namespace outer {

class ClassA
{
public:

    friend MyError ::FriendlyAccess();  // enum MyError is not a class or namespace

protected:

    int protectedMember();
};

} // Added missing terminator for namespace outer

using outer::ClassA;

int
ClassA::protectedMember()
{
    return 0;
}

MyError FriendlyAccess()
{
    ClassA a;

    std::cout << "Access Protected Method " << a.protectedMember() << std::endl;

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

The enumeration reference in the friend declaration will not compile under C++14 (gcc 8.3.1):

```
friend.cpp:17:37: error: ‘enum MyError’ is not a class or a namespace
     friend MyError ::FriendlyAccess();
                                     ^
friend.cpp:17:37: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘FriendlyAccess’ with no type [-fpermissive]
friend.cpp: In function ‘MyError FriendlyAccess()’:
friend.cpp:38:66: error: ‘int outer::ClassA::protectedMember()’ is protected within this context
     std::cout << "Access Protected Method " << a.protectedMember() << std::endl;
                                                                  ^
friend.cpp:29:1: note: declared protected here
 ClassA::protectedMember()
```

Declaring ClassA in the global namespace allows the code to compile successfully.  Is there a correct way to reference the C style enum from inside the namespace on a friend declaration in later versions of C++?

**UPDATE**

- C-style enums are legacy code
- Added missing "}" terminator for namespace outer
- Removing the "::" global scope delimiter allows the friend declaration to compile, but grants friendship to outer::FriendlyAccess instead
- Trailing return type, as suggested by IICapitano, does compile successfully

  friend auto ::FriendlyAccess() -> MyError;

Comment: Removing the `::` before `FriendlyAccess` [works](https://godbolt.org/z/s51nns). I don't really understand if you use the c-style definitions on purpose because of legacy code or not...

Comment: My guess is that `MyError ::FriendlyAccess` is just ignoring the whitespace, and you get a weird parsing of that...

Comment: Where should `namespace outer` end? There's no closing `}` in your code.

Comment: Using a trailing return type for `FriendlyAccess` [works](https://godbolt.org/z/8KeP69) assuming the end of `namespace outer` is right after the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [friend statement takes a function declaration or definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend).

When removing the `::`, you end up declaring another FriendlyAccess function, this time from inside the `outer` namespace. That works if you put the FriendlyAccess definition inside the workspace too (then your initial declaration in the global namespace is unused).

The compiler seems to interpret `friend MyError ::FriendlyAccess();` as trying to friend a member method of class MyError (which is legal) and doesn't see that it could also be your existing free function.

Using auto and trailing return type makes it understand it's a free function

```
friend auto ::FriendlyAccess() -> MyError;
```